# Why one .net library needs the reference of the dependency of other .net library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I am facing a weird problem. I have multiple .net standard class projects in my solution. There is one .net **standard 2.0** class library project called Messaging (`.csproj`) which uses **ActiveMQ** to push and read data from it. This project reference to Apache.NMS library. Now I have another project called **Core** (`.csproj`) which references to the Messaging project. During the constructor call of the class inside Messaging project in Core project, I get the error that System could not find Apache.NMS dll. If I add this reference in the Core project then everything works fine but I really do not understand why this is happening. With a pure .net framework thing, I never faced this issue. Separate projects with their own references and working independently.
Can anyone help with it?
I have added all references from nuget

Answer (score 0):

After lot of research i found the solution of this problem. What was happening is in the bin folder of the .NET framework / standard project the dependent dll of the referenced projects were not getting copied.

**Solution for .NET Framework project:**
Open .csproj file and add below line in the first  tag

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
```

**Solution for .NET Standard / Core project:**
Open .csproj file and add below line the first  tag

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Now compile the projects and you will see all the required dll's are present in the bin folder.
Hope this help someone else who is facing the same issue.